# "Cast to ObjectId failed for value" when querying subdocument [Mongoose]

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to be able to access a subdocument using its id, without necessarily knowing the id of the parent. I have the following mongoose schema:

```
var subdocumentSchema = mongoose.Schema({ 
      data: String
})

var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({                                                                                                      
     firstname : String,                                                                                                              
     lastname : String,                                                                                                           
     subdocument: [subdoumentSchema]
})
```

Which i use to create the following object:

```
{
    "_id":"5a36c5d211e4892747300363",
    "firstname": "Person",
    "lastname":"Personson",
    "subdocument": 
    [{
         "_id":"5a5ccd4905a74e65945b6a0a",
         "data" : ...
    }]
}
```

In the mongo console, I am able to find the document using the subdocument id with the following query: `db.users.find({"subdocument._id": ObjectId("5a5ccd4905a74e65945b6a0a")})`

However, I am unable to the same with mongoose. `User.findById({'contactRequests._id': '5a5ccd4905a74e65945b6a0a'})` merely produces a *Cast to ObjectId failed for value*-error.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: No, that was just a mistake when I wrote the post. I've fixed it now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was using `findById` instead of `findOne`. By using `findById`, `{'contactRequests._id': '5a5ccd4905a74e65945b6a0a'}` was parsed as an ID itself, which was not what I wanted.